# Set default padding on ComboBox dependent on IsEditable property

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have set all my TextBoxes and ComboBoxes to have a default Padding of "1,3".  When a ComboxBox is editable, the padding looks identical to the TextBoxes.  But when `IsEditable` is defaulted to false, the padding doesn't look the same.

In App.xaml I already have:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1,3"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1,3"/>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

In App.xaml, how can I set all ComboBoxes with an `IsEditable="False"` property to have `Padding="6,3,5,3"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a trigger to change the padding based on the property (in your case `IsEditable`) of the ComboBox. To do this, style your `ComboBox` like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1,3"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,3,5,3"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a great opportunity to use a keyed style on all applicable ComboBoxes:

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox" x:Key="EditableComboBoxStyle">
    <Setter Property="IsEditable" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,3,5,3"/>
</Style>
```

Add this as a keyed resource in your `App.xaml`and apply it like so:

```
<ComboBox Style={StaticResource EditableComboBoxStyle}"/>
```

This will override your default style for any ComboBox to which you apply it.